# optimising a pandas join/finding more memory efficient way

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I want help in improving a join, which takes in data of ever increasing size. We have two data sets temp1 as:

```
Muid advertiserid content 

1     100          1

1     100          2

1     100         56

1     101         1

1     101         34

and temp2 as:

Muid advertiserid content  approved

1     100          1        1

1     101          1        0

1     100         56        0

1     200         1         1

1     100         2         1
```

Objective is to populate the users of table 1 as approved or not based on the linkage of muid content and advertiserid.
Now I am joining these two dataframes as:

```
recos=pd.merge(temp1,temp2,how='left',left_on=['muid','content','advertiserid'],right_on=['muid','content','advertiserid'])
```

Earlier this join executed perfectly,but as the size of input, especially temp1 is growing and is currently has millions of rows, this gives me memory error on the execution.

Can someone suggest me a better way to accomplish the task.